# Deleting a partially cancelled-copy file VB.NET

Tags: .net, vb.net, file, stream, file-copying

What would be the best approach for deleting a file that has been cancelled during a copy? What i did was if I click the `Cancel` button a `Timer` will be enabled and check if the file exists, If it is, then it will delete the file then the timer will be disabled and vice versa. Here's my code:

```
Private Sub btnCancel_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnCancel.Click
    Timer3.Enabled = True 
End Sub
```

The `updatedFiles` is a `List(Of String)` that contains files that has been put there before copying them.

```
Private Sub Timer3_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer3.Tick
    Dim dest As String = Label6.Text
        For i = 0 To updatedFilesCancel.Count - 1
             File.Delete(Path.Combine(dest, updatedFilesCancel(i)))
             Timer3.Enabled = False
        Next
End Sub
```

the `Timer` has a 1 sec. interval, It deletes successfully for **ONCE**, the second time it doesn't work anymore, what seems to be the problem? suggestions?

Comment: Why do u need a timer?

Comment: Uhm that's only way i can think of. Because i'm using the `FileStream` to copy the files and if i delete the files after i cancel the copy an error throws `the file is being used` so i wait for the `FileStream` to finish its process before deleting.

Comment: Here how I do it: `If file.Exists("path") Then File.Delete("path")` Waht is the difference was it canceled or not?

Comment: If the file count is not in 100s, don't worry about timer or threading. Just move the timer code into your Cancel button code and get rid of the Timer.

Comment: If the file count is high enough taht it would take a lot of time, then use `Threading` or `BackgroundWorker` control.

Comment: Work on a separate thread and use `Threading.Thread.Sleep` if you want to wait for some time.

Comment: can you give some sample code please?

Comment: If you're using a FileStream to read/write bytes, then your cancel button can just set a CancelFileCopy variable = true. And in your Filestream loop, just check if that variable = true, then exit the loop, close the stream and delete the file. Then it moves on to the next file or stops the copy process completely.

Answer (score 1):

I will suggest you to use a **[Task](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)** with a **[CancellationTokenSource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.cancellationtokensource(v=vs.110).aspx)**, instead of messing with timers, it will give you better control and behavior of a file-copy operation.

I implemented all that in a simple class named **[FileCopy](https://github.com/ElektroStudios/ElektroKit/blob/master/Solution/v1.2/Elektro.IO/Types/FileCopy.vb)** that serves to demonstarte an example.

[image: https://github.com/ElektroStudios/ElektroKit/blob/master/Solution/v1.2/Elektro.IO/Types/FileCopy.vb]

If you don't like it, you could take the source-code and adapt it for your needs, or just see how managed the things in my source-code to make this by your own!.

An example:

```
Imports Elektro.IO.Types

Public Class Form1 : Inherits Form

    Friend WithEvents FileCopier As FileCopy
    Private fileCopyCancelToken As CancellationTokenSource

    Private Sub ButtonStart_Click() Handles Button1.Click

        Me.FileCopier = New FileCopy("C:\Source File.ext")

        ' It returns a CancellationTokenSource to cancel the task whenever you want.
        Me.fileCopyCancelToken = Me.FileCopier.CopyTo("C:\Target file.ext",
                                                      overwrite:=True,
                                                      deleteFileOnCancel:=True,
                                                      cancelCallback:=Nothing)

    End Sub

    Private Sub ButtonCancel_Click() Handles Button2.Click

        Me.fileCopyCancelToken.Cancel()

    End Sub

    Private Sub FileCopier_ProgressChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As FileCopyProgressChangedEventArgs) _
    Handles FileCopier.FileCopyProgressChanged

        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Copied: {0:0.00}%", e.Percentage))

    End Sub

End Class
```

This other (more extended) example can be found in the source-code:

```
Public Class Form1 : Inherits Form

    Friend WithEvents FileCopier As FileCopy
    Private fileCopyCancelToken As CancellationTokenSource

    Private Sub Button1_Click() Handles Button1.Click

        Me.StartCopy()

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click() Handles Button2.Click

        Me.CancelCopy()

    End Sub

    Private Sub StartCopy()

        ' Create a dummy file of 2 GB
        Using fs As New FileStream("C:\source file.ext", FileMode.CreateNew)
            fs.SetLength(2147483648)
        End Using

        Me.FileCopier = New FileCopy("C:\source file.ext")

        Me.fileCopyCancelToken =
            Me.FileCopier.CopyTo("C:\Target file.ext",
                                 bufferSize:=(CInt(Me.FileCopier.File.Length \ (1024 * 100)) + 1),
                                 overwrite:=True,
                                 deleteFileOnCancel:=False,
                                 cancelCallback:=AddressOf Me.FileCopier_CancelCallBack)

    End Sub

    Private Sub CancelCopy()

        ' Cancel the current file-copy operation.
        Me.FileCopier.CancelCopy(Me.fileCopyCancelToken)

    End Sub

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Callback that is called when the a file-copy operaton of the <see cref="FileCopier"/> is cancelled.
    ''' </summary>
    Private Sub FileCopier_CancelCallBack()

        Me.Invoke(
            Sub()
                Me.Label1.Text = "Canceled!"
                Me.Label2.Text = "Canceled!"
                Me.Label3.Text = "Canceled!"
                Me.Label4.Text = "Canceled!"
            End Sub)
    End Sub

    ''' ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ''' <summary>
    ''' Handles the <see cref="FileCopy.FileCopyProgressChanged"/> event of the <see cref="FileCopier"/> instance.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ''' <param name="sender">
    ''' The source of the event.
    ''' </param>
    ''' 
    ''' <param name="e">
    ''' The <see cref="FileCopyProgressChangedEventArgs"/> instance containing the event data.
    ''' </param>
    ''' ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Private Sub FileCopier_FileCopyProgressChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As FileCopyProgressChangedEventArgs) _
    Handles FileCopier.FileCopyProgressChanged

        Me.Invoke(
            Sub()
                Me.Label1.Text = String.Format("Size: {0} MB", (e.Filesize / 1024).ToString("n2"))
                Me.Label2.Text = String.Format("Written: {0} MB", (e.BytesRead / 1024).ToString("n2"))
                Me.Label3.Text = String.Format("Read: {0} MB", (e.BytesRemaining / 1024).ToString("n2"))
                Me.Label4.Text = String.Format("Done: {0}%", e.Percentage.ToString("n2"))
            End Sub)

    End Sub

End Class
```

I hope this can help you.